# Immutable.Record typings behavior changed in typescript 3.4.1. Upcasting no longer works

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

> EDIT:
>   looks like this is happening because of [this change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#consistent-inference-priorities-outside-of-strictfunctiontypes) in typescript 3.4 ( thanks @jcalz). Any ideas on how to support upcasting with strict function types turned on?

I just recently updated from typescript 3.3.3 to typescript 3.4.1 and the following code no longer works:

It looks like before typescript 3.4.1 we were allowed to upcast from Immutable.Record<B> to Immutable.Record<A> but after the update, that's no longer allowed. Is that intentional?

```
interface A { a: string }
interface B extends A { b: string }

const RecordA = Immutable.Record<A>({ a: '1' })
const RecordB = Immutable.Record<B>({ a: '1', b: '2' })
let c: Immutable.Record<A> & Readonly<A> = RecordB() 
/* You can no longer assign typeof RecordB to RecordA even though it has all the properties of Record A. This used to work before typescript 3.4.1 */
```

This makes writing shared functions like this much harder as you would have to cast an instance of RecordB to RecordA explicitly in order to pass the type checking properly.

```
function someSharedFunction(arg: Immutable.Record<A>) {
  //...
}
```

Is there another way to write this code so that we can write shared code more easily? Or is there something we can change in the typings to make this case work?

Here's the error message

````
  Type 'Record<B> & Readonly<B>' is not assignable to type 'Record<A>'.
    Types of property 'has' are incompatible.
      Type '(key: string) => key is "b" | "a"' is not assignable to type '(key: string) => key is "a"'.
        Type predicate 'key is "b" | "a"' is not assignable to 'key is "a"'.
          Type '"b" | "a"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
            Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.ts(2322)```
````

Comment: Could it be [this change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#consistent-inference-priorities-outside-of-strictfunctiontypes)?  I don't have immutable.js in my environment so I can't debug it easily

Comment: Looks like that was it. I could reproduce this problem with "strictFunctionTypes" set to true on typescript 3.3. Any ideas on how to support upcasting with strictFunctionTypes turned on?

Comment: Uh, give up on `has(x)` acting as a type guard?  It's not safe to narrow `x` to `keyof T` when `T` is something like `{a: string}` but the actual value being held is of type`{a: string, b: string}`.  If `has(x)` is changed to just return a `boolean` the issue might go away.  But that probably breaks people who rely on the type guard.

Comment: Hmm, I can see that working but yeah that would be a big change to the immutable.js typings. Not sure how others would feel